# solr core initialization error

Tags: tomcat, solr

I added a new core to solr. It was working perfectly.

Then I modified schema.xml and I cut-paste the matter in this file instead of doing this from terminal. Since than solr is unable to detect this core. I tried to solve this but unfortunately the default core Collection1 is also not initializing.

Comment: Can you please provide the details? What is the SOLR version? How did you add SOLR core? What did you modify by cut-paste? Do you see any error during initialization?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. The issue is resolved now.